# CMD how can I return multiple strings between two tags

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am using Windows CMD

I have a webpage saved as a .txt and now I want to return the texts that are between

```
multiple <p> and </p> tags.
```

can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Not that it can't be done, but if I were you.. I would try to do this using a different language.  I love writing batch using cmd but processing text files with special chars like `<` , `>`, `|` is VERY VERY painful. Batch is not great at processing text.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no easy way to do this in CMD/Batch, however, if you can switch to PowerShell you can use the following.

> I know this isn't *exactly* answering your question, but it might work better
> for you since PowerShell is more powerful and is related to CMD.

If `data.txt` contains (for example)...

```
<p>test</p>
<p>abcd</p>
```

This PowerShell command will get the txt file, match anything between the `<p>` and `</p>` tags, then for each match, return the inner value.

```
Get-Content .\data.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match "<p>(.*?)</p>" } | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] }
```

Result:

```
test
abcd
```

Proof:
[image: example of PowerShell command]